# How to get request type (master/sub) in Symfony2 controller?

Tags: symfony

Is there possible get request type in controller? How?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To detect if the request is a master or not requires the use of the `RequestStack`, which should be injected into your controller. The request stack has 3 useful methods

```
getCurrentRequest();
getMasterRequest();
getParentRequest();
```

The `getParentRequest()` will always return null if the current request is the master.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this myself, and it seems it is just passed around, so there doesn't seem to be one single place that knows what it is.

My thought for solving this would be to create a simple kernel.request listener that just adds an attribute to the request.  Rough (un-tested) code below:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('_request_type', $event->getRequestType());
}
```

Then in the controller you should be able to do:

```
$requestType = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_request_type');
```

Again this is untested. You would need to write out the full listener class and add it to the services config file, but other than that I think this will work.

Answer (score -2):

Easy, just call the `getMethod()` method on your `Request` object:

```
$method = $this->get('request')->getMethod();
```

This will return the HTTP method of the current request, e.g. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE`.

Comment: Noo. I mean: is this request master or sub-request?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that. In that case you'll have to hook into the `kernel.request` event and check if `$event->getRequestType()` is equal to `HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST` or `HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST`.

Comment: @igorw, you should update you post with the answer you gave in your comment so it can be upvoted. People don't upvote an answer not answering the question.