# How can I check if request was a POST or GET request in Symfony2 or Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, request, http-post, http-get

I just wondered if there is a very easy way (best: a simple `$this->container->isGet()` I can call) to determine whether the request is a `$_POST` or a `$_GET` request.

According to the docs,

> A Request object holds information about the client request. This
>   information can be accessed via several public properties:
>
> - `request`: equivalent of `$_POST`;
> - `query`: equivalent of `$_GET` (`$request->query->get('name')`);

But I won't be able to use `if($request->request)` or `if($request->query)` to check, because both are existing attributes in the Request class.

So I was wondering of Symfony offers something like the

```
$this->container->isGet();
// or isQuery() or isPost() or isRequest();
```

mentioned above?

Comment: you can do like $request->get('name').whatever request method is post or get..if u really want to determine request method you can add a "requirements: [_method: POST/GET/DELETE....]"

Comment: You mean adding this line to the routing config? I do check restrict methods there and now I want to determine them in controller.

Comment: if u check restrict methods in your route,then just use $request->get('name') in your controller,that's enough

Comment: I am using one controller to handle both methods, e.g. as in forms (where you can use `$form->isSubmitted()` to check this. But in my case I don't have/use a form.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you want to do it in controller,

```
$this->getRequest()->isMethod('GET');
```

or in your model (service), inject or pass the Request object to your model first, then do the same like the above.

**Edit**: for Symfony 3 use this code

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, also found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6723808/1828051

Comment: As MHakvoort also mentioned in his answer, `$this->getRequest()` is deprecated as of Symfony 2.4.

Answer (score 46):

Or this:

```
public function myAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have updated the question name so people can find it if searching

Answer (score 6):

Or this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST' ) {
}
```

Comment: this is most likely ok for slim but Symfony best practice is to use dependency injection. However, your solution still works in Symfony 5.

Comment: thumbs up for this savior! it works in Symfony 6.1 too.

Answer (score 4):

Since the answer suggested to use `getRequest()` which is now deprecated,
You can do it by this:

```
$this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST'
```

Comment: This is also deprecated. In controller, you should only use the typehinted $request object. For example, $request->getMethod() == 'POST'.

Answer (score 2):

In addition - if you prefer using constants:

```
if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {}
```

See the Request class:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

class Request
{
    public const METHOD_HEAD = 'HEAD';
    public const METHOD_GET = 'GET';
    public const METHOD_POST = 'POST';
    public const METHOD_PUT = 'PUT';
    public const METHOD_PATCH = 'PATCH';
    public const METHOD_DELETE = 'DELETE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if($this->request->getRealMethod() == 'post') {
    // is post
}

if($this->request->getRealMethod() == 'get') {
    // is get
}
```

Just read a bit about [request](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object on [Symfony API](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/) page.